# JUnit java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, testing, junit

Im new to software testing, i keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException for some reason and i don't know what it is

This is what i am testing on

```
public int getNumberOfStudents()
    {
        int validStudents = 0;
        int i = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        do {
            if (students[i] != null && students[i].exists())
                validStudents++;
            else
                done = true;
            i++;
        } while(i < students.length && !done);

        return validStudents;
    } // end of getNumberOfStudents



This is the test case



class Testing {

    RegistrationSystem GNS = new RegistrationSystem();

    @Test
    //@SpiraTestCase(testCaseId=5487)
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("validStudents", GNS.getNumberOfStudents());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the NPE thrown from and how is students initialized? This question will probably be closed nonetheless

Comment: Where is the NPE happening?

Comment: Your `assertEquals` statement is almost certainly wrong. You're asserting that the string literal `"validStudents"` is equal to the `int` that is returned from calling `getNumberOfStudents` - this comparison will always fail

Answer (score 0):

I guess at line `if (students[i] != null && students[i].exists())` you have not initialized students while creating RegistrationSystem Object, create it and it will work also I can see a problem in assert that you are comparing string with int :)`assertEquals("validStudents", GNS.getNumberOfStudents());`

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you getting error. 
One problem with your test case is you are comparing string "validstudents" with integer returned from function GNS.getNumberOfStudents(). You need to set a number of students, then call getNumberOfStudents() assert it with the expected value.